# Jmeter - Force close a socket/wait until message recieved

Tags: sockets, groovy, jmeter, serversocket, jmeter-5.0

I am opening a socket in jmeter (using groovy in JSR223 Sampler), and storing the message in a jmeter variable. This is the below code:

```
SocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new  InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),4801);
def server = new ServerSocket()
server.bind(inetSocketAddress)

while(!vars.get("caseId"))) {
    server.accept { socket ->
        log.info('Someone is connected')
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          String str;
          while((str = reader.readLine())!= null){
             sb.append(str);
          }
          String finalStr = sb.toString()
          String caseId = finalStr.split("<caseId>")[1].split("</caseId>")[0]
          vars.put("caseId", caseId)
        }
        log.info("Connection processed")
    }
}
if(vars.get("caseId"))
{
    try
    {
        server.close();
        vars.put("socketClose",true);   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.info("Error in closing the socket: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now, there is some time delay between the first loop is executed and the message being recieved from the port. It doesnt receive the message immediately, and hence while loop is executed again. And then message is received and it sets *caseId*. It goes on to close the socket, because caseId is set. And that is throwing the error, because socket is still waiting for the message. So is there a way, to wait until socket has recieved all the messages, so i could properly close it?

Or just force close the socket, and Jmeter wont throw any exception?

Or when i execute next component, say IF controller in Jmeter, it waits until variable socketClose is set true? In that way, instead of while loops inside JSR223 sampler, i could use multiple If Controllers in Jmeter thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is how [ServerSocket.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close()) function works

> public void close()
> throws IOException
>
> Closes this socket. **Any thread currently blocked in accept() will throw a SocketException.**

I don't think there is a way "to wait until socket has recieved all the messages" because Socket is dump as a rock and it can either listen for connections or shut down.

Maybe you might be interested in [setSoTimeout() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int))?

Also this line:

```
vars.put("socketClose",true)
```

is very suspicious, I think you need to change it either to:

```
vars.put("socketClose", "true")
```

or to

```
vars.putObject("socketClose",true)
```

as [JMeterVariables.put() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) can accept only a String, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.